# Select X windows using the keyboard like ace-jump / hint following or similar

Tags: x11

A lot of tools provide a way of selecting things with the keyboard.
Normally this works by popping up some sort of labelled menu of items and then pressing a key. Examples: vimeperator follow hint, ace-jump mode.
Here's a screencast of the sort of thing I want: http://emacsrocks.com/e10.html.

Is there an analogous way of selecting windows in X, popping up labels on each window and pressing the appropriate key? Or anything easy which is quite similar?

Comment: It's certainly possible in principle, but the application must be written to support it. Which application did you have in mind? If you are talking about "windows", do you mean your window manager, and do you want keyboard shortcuts to select windows? If yes, which window manager are you using?

Comment: @dirkt I've clarified my question a little based on this. I happen to be using *i3wm* but would hope that if a tool existed for this it could be window manager agnostic. I want a keyboard shortcut to *easily* jump to the correct window. I already use keyboard shortcuts to navigate around windows (i3 is tiling)

Comment: It can't be window manager agnostic, because it's the job of the window manager to select windows. However, one can interact with certain WMs using a protocol, as e.g. done in `wmctrl`. So it certainly would be possible to write such a tool, or modify a WM to do it. But I'm not aware of a WM or a tool that does it in that style.

Comment: `the job of window managers to select`. Interesting, I'd assume that this was an X thing, but the line between X and the window manager is a bit blurry in my mind. `xdotool` has a `windowfocus` command but I don't know if this is actually using [EWMH](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) under the hood

Comment: If you look at `man xdotool`, it says *Uses XSetInputFocus which may be ignored by some **window managers** or programs* right under `windowfocus`. The mechanism is: You tell X to set focus, but the WM intercepts it, just like it intercepts other X calls, and does whatever it likes. You can also configure WMs for different focus policies, e.g. "click to focus" or "enter to focus".

Comment: There's this: https://github.com/loki42/easyxmotion. Unfortunately, it won't work as-is since python-wnck isn't a thing anymore. Perhaps you can modify it, though.